# How to Troubleshoot TFS 2010 Build Notifications

Tags: build-process, build-automation

So, I have been having a bear of a time trying to troubleshoot why build alerts/notifications are not working for me in TFS 2010.  The short of what has happened is that another individual installed the core components for TFS 2010 about six months ago but none of the build components.  These previously installed components are all working correctly.

A few weeks back, I installed the remaining build component piece which appears to be working correctly.  I have a build controller and a build agent set up which appear to function as well.  I can get latest from source control, make changes, check in and associate to a work item as part of a changeset, build that change set, and get a build report.  All appears to be well.  However, when I attempt to change the build quality (from blank to Under Investigation, for instance) I don't get any alerts.

To be clear, I have installed the TFS 2010 power tools.  This has a tool called Alert Explorer which allows you to view event notification subscriptions.  When creating a change set, I do receive an email alert as expected (this is part of the "core" installation I mentioned earlier).  Unfortunately, when changing the build quality or completing a build (either success or failure) I receive no emails even though I've confirmed the subscription in the Alert Explorer.

Please, if anyone knows how I can troubleshoot, diagnose, and correct the build notifications I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try diagnosing email and soap subscription failures as described by Grant Holliday here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2009/10/28/tfs2010-diagnosing-email-and-soap-subscription-failures.aspx

Something might turn up.